# Date and Time - My export table is showing TimeStamp even though "Date Only" selected

Tags: 2013, list, spservices, date, timestamp

My list is showing "24 November, 2017 (without TimeStamp)"

The code on my index page is showing date in Numerals (11/24/17 and with TimeStamp) e.g. 2017-11-24 01:00:00

1) How do i remove the TimeStamp?
2) How do I change it to showing '24 November' instead of numerals?

```
var query = "<Query>
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Date' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>
</Query>";
```

Full code:

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript> get() ;
function get() { var method = "GetListItems";                
var webURL =  $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() ;                    
var list = "MyLibraries";                     
var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>"+"<FieldRef Name='Name' />" +"</ViewFields>";
var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Date' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>";           

$().SPServices  
({ operation: method, async: false, webURL: webURL, listName: list,
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
CAMLQuery: query, completefunc: function (xData, Status)
{ $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function()
{
var date  =  $(this).attr("ows_Date");

$("#myDataTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
"<td align='left'>" +date+ "'></td>" + "</tr>");

}); } }); };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint date time fields always contains date and time, the time portion is just set to 00:00 and hidden from UI if the field is set to date only.

One way to properly format your dates:

Use a more modern API such as the REST API, which returns the date time as UTC ("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ", e.g. "1994-11-05T13:15:30Z" ).
Then use JavaScript's built in date to adjust the time zone and format the string into an appropriate format, e.g. Date.toLocaleDateString:

```
var date = new Date(utcTimeStringFromSharePoint);
var formattedDateString = date.toLocaleDateString();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: Thanks for the swift response! Is there a way i can make tiny edits to the code above? I am not a REST API user :(.

Comment: If you go REST, in the end there will be less code and you wont have to rely on any 3rd party libraries. Here are some docs to get you started: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest ...

Comment: You MAY be able to use javascript (toLocaleDateString etc) with your current values as well, but make sure to check that time zones are correctly handled!